# An Efficient Non-Enforcing, Verifying, Mutex

Tags: multithreading, debugging, c++11, mutual-exclusion

Class `foo` has a method `bar`. According to some synchronization protocol, the `bar` method of a specific `foo` object, will be only called by at most one thread at any point in time.

I'd like to add a very lightweight `verification_mutex` to verify this / debug synchronization abuses. It will be used similarly to a regular mutex:

```
class foo {
public:
    void bar() {
        std::lock_guard<verification_mutex> lk{m};
        ...
    }

private:
    mutable verification_mutex m;
};
```

however, it will not in itself necessarily lock or unlock anything. Rather, it will just `throw` if multithreaded simultaneous access is detected. The point is to make its runtime footprint as low as possible (including its effect on other code, e.g., through [memory barriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier)).

Here are three options for implementing `verification_mutex`:

1. A wrapper around `std::mutex`, but with `lock` implemented by a check that `trylock` succeeded (this is just to get the idea; clearly not very fast)
2. An atomic variable noting the current "locking" thread id, with atomic `exchange` operations (see implementation sketch below).
3. Same as 2, but without atomics.

Are these correct or incorrect (in particular, 2 and esp. 3)? How will they affect performance (esp. of surrounding code)? Is there an altogether superior alternative?

---

**Edit** The answer by @SergeyA below is fine, but I'm in particular curious about the memory barriers. A solution not utilizing them would be great, as would be an answer giving some intuitive explanation why any solution omitting them would necessarily fail.

---

**Implementation Sketch**

```
#include <atomic>                                                                                                                                                                                            
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

class verification_mutex {
public:
    verification_mutex() : m_holder{0}{}

    void lock() {
        if(m_holder.exchange(get_this_thread_id()) != 0)
            throw std::logic_error("lock");
    }

    void unlock() {
        if(m_holder.exchange(0) != get_this_thread_id())
            throw std::logic_error("unlock");
    }

    bool try_lock() {
        lock();
        return true;
    }

private:
    static inline std::size_t get_this_thread_id() {
        return std::hash<std::thread::id>()(std::this_thread::get_id());
    }

private:
    std::atomic_size_t m_holder;
};
```

Comment: The trylock has to actually hold the lock, or you cannot detect if the other thread is "in there".  So it'll be no faster than a lock.  How strongly do you need to know of the error?  Reliably, or is this just testing?

Comment: Why are you trying to make reentrant lock?

Comment: Also, notice that adding any sort of synchronization will slow your down due to effect of memory barriers (and synchro without memory barriers is useless)

Comment: @Yakk This is just for testing (it might even go in using some debug-mode macro). The thing is that, even for testing, experience has shown me that you can't have slow debug mechanisms - they can change the contention patterns.

Comment: @SergeyA It's not a lock, per se, and not reentrant - it's something with a lock interface that just verifies that the access one thread at a time. About your second point about memory barriers - thanks, I mentioned that in the question. It's why I was wondering what implementation would minimize their adverse effects.

Comment: You are using thread id there. If you do not want it reentrant, you can just set it to 1 with `atomic_exchange_strong` and to 0 when unlocked. Atomic variables will be fastest, since there will no context switching associated with them - but still slower than no fence.

Comment: @SergeyA OK, thanks. Would that be similar to the sketched code, then? Also, feel free to write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Option 3 is not viable. You need a memory barrier when reading/writing a variable from multiple threads.

Of all options, atomic boolean variable would be the fastest, since it won't require context switches (mutexes might). Something like that:

```
class verifying_mutex {
   std::atomic<bool> locked{false};
public:
   bool lock() {
      if (!locked.compare_exchange_strong(false, true))
         throw std::runtime_error("Incorrect mt-access pattern");
   }

   bool unlock() {
      locked = false;
   }
};
```

On a side note, your original version of lock used thread_id, which would slow you down unnecessary. Do not do this.

Comment: Good point about the alternative to using a thread_id. It's a bit of a tradeoff, though, as the thread ids can be used for some diagnostics.